# Simple algebraic field extensions of prime degree

Tags: extension-field

Let $K(\alpha)/K$ be a simple algebraic field extension of prime degree $p$. Suppose $\beta \in K(\alpha)$ with $\beta\not\in K$ and $\beta\not=\alpha$. What can we say about $\beta$? Is it necessarily a $K$-conjugate of $\alpha$?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only say that $K(\beta)=K(\alpha)$.

$\beta$ is not necessarily a $K$-conjugate of $\alpha$. Consider for instance $\alpha=\sqrt 2$ and $\beta=1+\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there more connection between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: @Mary, of course, $\beta=f(\alpha)$ and $\alpha=g(\beta)$ with $f,g \in K[x]$.

Comment: How about when $K$ is of prime characteristic? Can we say anything more?